# nlohmann's json library convert an array to a vector of structs

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

Say I have a json array that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "test",
    "Val": "test_val"
  },
  {
    "Name": "test2",
    "Val": "test_val2"
  }
]
```

I want to convert this into a vector of structs:

```
struct Test {
  string Name;
  string Val;
};
```

I know about the `json.get<>()` method, but do not know how to apply that to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the automatic `get<>` to work, you need to provide a mapping between JSON and your struct:

```cpp
void from_json(const nlohmann::json& j, Test& p) {
    j.at("Name").get_to(p.Name);
    j.at("Val").get_to(p.Val);
}
```

Then it will work as expected.

```cpp
auto parsed = json.get<std::vector<Test>>();
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/9P1mjO