# JSON to an array of structs in nlohmann json lib

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60325894/nlohmanns-json-library-convert-an-array-to-a-vector-of-structs) question about converting an array of objects into a vector of structs. I want to do the same thing, but rather vectors I want an array. For example

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Test",
    "Val": "TestVal"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Test2",
    "Val": "TestVal2"
  }
]
```

And want an array of of these structs:

```
struct Test {
  string Name;
  string Val;
};
```

How can this be possible? I am new to c++ so if I am doing anything wrong please say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is use, wherever you can, `std::array` instead of C arrays. `std::array` is  a C++ analogue to plain arrays that adds all the nice stuff from `std::vector` like `size()` and iterators. You can also return them from functions, unlike C arrays.

nlohmann also supports it automatically:

```cpp
auto parsed = json.get<std::array<Test, 2>>();
```

Not sure about the library's support for plain ol' C arrays. But you can write a helper function with a little template magic:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t N>
void from_json(const nlohmann::json& j, T (&t)[N]) {
    if (j.size() != N) {
        throw std::runtime_error("JSON array size is different than expected");
    }
    size_t index = 0;
    for (auto& item : j) {
        from_json(item, t[index++]);
    }
}
```

usage:

```cpp
Test my_array[N];
from_json(json, my_array);
```

Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/-jDTdj