# Nlohmann's json library, json array to a vector of structs with pointers inside the struct

Tags: c++, json, pointers, struct, nlohmann-json

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60325894/nlohmanns-json-library-convert-an-array-to-a-vector-of-structs) post about converting a json array to a vector of structs. I have a struct named `Foo`:

```
typedef struct Foo {
  Foo* SubFoo;
} Foo;
```

and when I try to do this:

```
void from_json(const nlohmann::json& j, Foo& f) {
    j.at("SubFoo").get_to(f.SubFoo);
}
```

It gives me this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'nlohmann::basic_json<>::get_to(Foo*&) const'
 j.at("SubFoo").get_to(a.SubFoo);
```

So how can I get from json with a pointer to a value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just dereference the pointer:

```
void from_json(const nlohmann::json& j, Foo& f) {
    j.at("SubFoo").get_to(*f.SubFoo);
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/YsY6KX).

You'll have to ensure that you are not dereferencing an invalid pointer though.