# How to write a vector of structs to json file?

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

Basically, this question is inverse to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60325894/nlohmanns-json-library-convert-an-array-to-a-vector-of-structs).

I want to write a vector of structs

```cpp
struct Test {
  std::string Name;
  std::string Val;
};
```

into a file:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "test",
    "Val": "test_val"
  },
  {
    "Name": "test2",
    "Val": "test_val2"
  }
]
```

What I have so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
using nlohmann::json;

struct Test {
  std::string Name;
  std::string Val;
};

void to_json(json& j, const Test&  t)
{
    j = json{ {"Name", t.Name}, {"Val", t.Val} };
}

int main(){
    Test t1{"Max", "value1"};
    Test t2{"Kai", "value2"};

    json j1 = t1;
    json j2 = t2;

    std::ofstream o("test_out.json");
    o << std::setw(4) << j1 << std::endl;
    o << std::setw(4) << j2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

which gives me:

```
{
    "Name": "Max",
    "Val": "value1"
}
{
    "Name": "Kai",
    "Val": "value2"
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are writing two objects and the result is two objects in the file. You probably want to write a container of objects.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Thomas' hint in the comments, I got it working:

```cpp
int main(){
    Test t1{"Max", "value1"};
    Test t2{"Kai", "value2"};

    json j;
    j.push_back(t1);
    j.push_back(t2);

    std::ofstream o("test_out.json");
    o << std::setw(4) << j << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

gives

```
[
  {
    "Name": "test",
    "Val": "test_val"
  },
  {
    "Name": "test2",
    "Val": "test_val2"
  }
]
```